# integrity constraint violated - parent key not found (i'm new to Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please help me?
I have created all of my tables and insert statements and yet I am getting this error.

This is the table I am trying to insert data into:

```
CREATE TABLE Avatar 
(
Avatar_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT pk_Avatar PRIMARY KEY,
AvatarName VARCHAR(255),
DOB NUMBER(12),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Strength NUMBER(12),
Cost NUMBER(20),
Species_ID NUMBER(3), CONSTRAINT fk_Species_ID FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Species(Species_ID),
Weapon_ID NUMBER(3), CONSTRAINT f_Weapon_ID FOREIGN KEY (Weapon_ID) REFERENCES Weapon(Weapon_ID),
Player_ID NUMBER(3), CONSTRAINT fk_Player_ID FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Player(Player_ID)
);
```

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Avatar
VALUES (301,'Considia',05-04-15,'F',100,50,101,208,1);
```

The error:

"integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found" (SQL Developer)

integrity constraint (MS166.FK_SPECIES_ID) violated - parent key not found (SQL Plus)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does Species table contain the key 101?

Comment: Yes, it does - it is my first insert statement for the species table

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer to insert the data and I'm using SQL*Plus to check where the error is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referencing the correct keys?

Should this:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Species_ID FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Species(Species_ID),
```

Not be:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Species_ID FOREIGN KEY (Species_ID) REFERENCES Species(Species_ID),
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you so much.